# Pgadmin 4 restore database at a certain location

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I have a database I want to restore at certain location, my second hd. How I do this in PgAdmin 4?

Comment: You restore to a server not a location.

Answer (score 0):

1. If your *backup file* is at a certain location, select it in the [backup and restore dialog window](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/6.18/backup_and_restore.html).
2. If you want your database to save data to a certain location, you can achieve that with [tablespaces](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtablespace.html). You can move stuff in db between different tablespaces using an [`alter`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html) query.
3. If you want the database to save data by default and only to that certain location, you can install a new cluster/instance and set its [data directory](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-file-locations.html) to your desired location from the start, then restore your database to that. It's also possible to [move an existing cluster](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/upgrading.html) to a new location and do the same.